# Accessing custom rosbuild msgs in catkin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to access custom rosbuild msgs in catkin. I've tried using add_dependencies( .... ) but it did not work.

How do I include custom rosbuild packages and their msgs/srvs in catkin CMakeLists?
The catkin packages reside in catkin_ws and the rosbuild packages reside in rosbuild_ws.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65956/accessing-custom-rosbuild-msgs-in-catkin/) by [bplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/5233/bplant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot have a catkin package depend on a rosbuild package. Catkin packages provide a backwards compatibility layer to let rosbuild packages build on top, but it does not work the other way.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1